# activeX combo boxes

Tags: excel, combobox, activex, vba

I have a complex workbook that has a number of ActiveX Combo boxes which I choose over form controls for their customization options.  Inexplicably, ALL of the boxes stopped working this morning.  Literally, one minute they worked and then stopped completely.  I was not working on that sheet, but rather a different one.  There is no code attached to the combo boxes.  When in design mode, the properties box doesn't even come up.  Developer>Properties opens the worksheet properties only.  This problem is not associated with the workbook because older versions of the same sheet are acting the same way.  However, the compiled version of the workbook works fine.  This suggests corruption in Excel somehow, so I repaired Excel (Office 365).  No difference.
I deleted the combo box and replaced it and it is ok now, but that's not good enough for me.  I have many others to remove and replace, but why do I need to do this?  There are 180 other boxes that this happened to in the past and I simply used Data Validation for because I could not have this happen.  I distribute this workbook in a compiled version only, so if I was certain that this bizarre occurrence could not happened once its compiled, I will replace all of the boxes that don't work and replace all of the data validation boxes with activeX, and compile it immediately.  But I like things to make sense.  What the heck is going on?

Answer (score 0):

An ActiveX combo box has it's code on the sheet module for the sheet it is in.  So, it's not odd that looking for the properties of the combo box that the sheet module would pop up.  When in design mode and you right click on the combo box a pop up menu should come up that allows you to click and see the box's code on the sheet module.  Are you saying that all the code for the boxes vanished or you had never written it?  How do they get populated?  I apologize for commenting in the answer section but I don't have enough points yet to write in the comment section.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that no one has answered this suggests that this is behavior that I am causing. My belief at this point is that there is code running in the background which suspends other activity. I have a pop up calendar that ends with a range selection. I believe that this is looping somehow. 
I am going to replace the data validation boxes with more combo boxes throughout the sheet with the calendar code in mind.